# When exactly is DateTime.Now updated?

Tags: c#, datetime, timer

I know that `DateTime.Now` (or `DateTime.UtcNow`) is only accurate to the system timer resolution. There's an "undocumented" function [NtSetTimerResolution](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/Time/NtSetTimerResolution.html) but it [doesn't affect the current time](http://forum.sysinternals.com/ntsettimerresolution_topic3046.html). I'm already using a hybrid solution of a start value from `DateTime.UtcNow` and an added `Stopwatch` counter for highest precision down to microseconds. That works pretty well actually, it just doesn't compare with time values coming from multiple processes on a system.

I'd like to further calibrate my base time now. And if the accuracy of `DateTime.Now` cannot be increased, at least I'd like to know when its value is updated to the next value. I'm thinking of a loop that spins so long until the value has changed, then use it and start the Stopwatch immediately.

Something like this: (untested)

```
DateTime t0 = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime baseTime;
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
while ((baseTime = DateTime.UtcNow) == t0);
stopwatch.Start();
```

Is my assumption correct that waiting for the value to change gives me the moment in which the reported value is accurate? If I do that in all my applications that report to a common log, for instance, I should be getting time values that are far more comparable than now. (I don't want to get synchronisation-level accuracy though, just better information.)

I've done a little test with the NtSetTimerResolution function, setting it up to the maximum resolution and comparing `DateTime.UtcNow` values in a loop then. It seems the values are more precise/accurate (can't distinguish here). But I'm not sure what I'm seeing here. And the current resolution at the start of the program was different every time. Not sure whether it interferes with other processes, so I'd prefer not to tinker with it in production code.

Comment: Are you really *just* interested in ordering? What sort of "accurate" are you talking about? (The "absolute" accuracy will depend on the accuracy of the system clock to some absolute clock such as an NTP server of course.)

Comment: If you are interested in tighter time measurements, that tight while loop will consume a lot of CPU cycles...and might affect the task you are measuring.

Comment: Local accuracy is enough. Windows is using an NTP source every couple days by default, that'll do. And of course this loop is only done once at process initialisation. Further I'll use `baseTime.Add(stopwatch.Elapsed)`. The loop should take no more than 16 ms.

Comment: The clock that DateTime.Now uses is updated by the clock interrupt, a signal generated by the chipset that wakes up the cpu.  It normally ticks 64 times per second.  You should see that back in your Stopwatch value.  That clock interrupt rate can be changed, some misbehaving programs use timeBeginPeriod() to alter it.  Start up Chrome for example and watch the effect it has on your measurement.  Which answers [this blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2013/10/why-does-windows-have-terrible-battery-life.html) by Jeff Atwood.

Comment: @HansPassant: Unfortunately Windows, from XP up to the newest 8.1 desktop, uses `timeBeginPeriod /NtSetTimeResolution` too. And it does not only affect the power consumption, it produces jumps in system time on Windows < 8.

Comment: @LonelyPixel: Have added some more details to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`NtSetTimerResolution()` does change the systems timer resolution. In this sense it seems very similar to `timeBeginPeriod`/`timeEndPeriod`. But NtSetTimerResolution may enable timer resolutions below 1 ms on hardware which supports higher resolution. Use `NtQueryTimerResolution` to investigate the limits. Most modern hardware running Windows above XP do support 0.5 ms resolution.

How does this affect the time? Well, on Windows > XP the granularity of the system time (system file time) or the update interval of the system time is determined by the systems heartbeat which is given by the timer resolution.

Examples:

1) Windows 7, NtQueryTimerResolution returns a maximum resolution of 5000 (100 ns units). NtSetTimerResolution allows to set the systems heartbeat to 0.5 ms. The system time (use GetSystemTimeAsFileTime to get appropriate resolution to detect) will increment in steps of 0.5 ms. So the current time is influenced, it's granularity changes.

2) Windows > XP, timeBeginPeriod(1) changes the systems heartbeat to 1 ms, but the granularity of time remains low. The system time granularity does not depend on the timer resolution on Windows XP.

*... function NtSetTimerResolution but it doesn't affect the current time.*

It does. [MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) *Use caution when calling timeBeginPeriod, as frequent calls can significantly affect the system clock, system power usage, and the scheduler.* However, MS failed to update the documentation here; the effect to the system time has been taken out with the Windows 8.1 timekeeping scheme. BTW: `timeBeginPeriod` **and** `timeEndPeriod`do use `NtSetTimerResolution`.

Hint: Call NtSetTimerResolution, timeBeginPeriod, and timeEndPeriod at the transition of the system time to reduce the effect. This can be accomplished by polling a system time transition ahead of the call.

*... added Stopwatch counter for highest precision down to microseconds.* Unfortunately `Stopwatch` does not take system time adjustments into account. You'd have to query for the actual system time adjustment ([GetSystemTimeAdjustment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  and apply the gain obtained by this call to the stopwatch frequency.

**Summary:** Is it more *...precise/accurate (can't distinguish here).*? It has a finer granularity which implies both: Precision and Accuracy.

**Note:** There are complaints about running the system at high frequency heartbeats as described here. Microsoft states that the power consumption raises by as much as 25%. Other write about lots of Megawatts lost due to high frequency heartbeats. As usual, the more you pay, the more you get.